# Input a list of tuples and look for the intersection + etc

Tags: python

A billboard is divided into vertical strips that are all of the same width. A series of posters are successively attached to the board. The posters have the same height as the billboard itself, are attached at different positions on the billboard, and thereby exactly cover a sequence of strips. However, the poster are not all of the same width, and are possibly stuck on top of each other. How many posters will finally be (partially) visible.
Write a function visible that takes a list of tuples, where each tuple contains two integers. The tuples describe the positions and the order of a sequence of posters that are attached on a billboard. The first tuple corresponds to the poster that is attached first. The last tuple with the poster that is attached at the end. The first integer of a tuple gives the index of the strip that is covered by the left part of the poster, and the second integer indicates the number of strips covered by the poster. The function should return how many posters are eventually (partially) visible.

The problem is available: https://www.spoj.com/problems/PROG0412.pdf

```
def zichtbaar(l):
    count = 0, 0
    breedte = []
    for item in l:
        positie = tuple((item[0], item[0] + item[1]))

    if positie[0] >= count[0]:
        count = positie
        print(count)

zichtbaar([(1, 4), (2, 5), (8, 3), (3, 2), (7, 4)])
```

Don't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried and made this:

```
def billboard_creator(seq):
    seq = [sum(elem) for elem in seq]
    bill_len = max(seq)-1
    return ['']  * bill_len

def find_posters(billboard, posters):
    for posternum, (start, length) in enumerate(posters):
        billboard[start : start + length] = [posternum] *  length
    return billboard


post_seq = [(1, 4), (2, 5), (8, 3), (3, 2), (7, 4)]

def find_post_num(post_seq):
    empty_billboard = billboard_creator(post_seq)
    final_billboard = find_posters(empty_billboard, post_seq)
    if '' in final_billboard:
        return len(set(final_billboard))-1
    return len(set(final_billboard))

print(find_post_num(post_seq))
```

Note this is not at all the best way to solve this but i think it helps in terms of understanding how to solve the problem

So I've divided the problem in 3 main parts:
In the first part I made a function to find the minimal length of the billboard. I made this by finding the poster where the start and length of the poster had the maximum value and then return an list made of n empty strings with n being that maximum value minus 1 (because the poster, for example, in the poster (7, 4) , starts at 7, not 8.

I then made another function that loops through the posters sequence and substitutes the indexes of the empty_billboard with the posters (Placing a different value in the billboard based on the index in post_seq of the poster)

I then call both functions in a last one and i check all the unique values in the billboard and subtract one if there is '' (so there is no poster there)

I tried with all the 3 test cases provided and it worked

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This may work for you:

Simply reverse the order of your input tuple (with the posters) and then check which of the tuples are not covered by the previous ones. One way of doing this is by setting up a dictionary which contains all the strips (i.e. integers representing the strip) which have been previously covered. Then, to check if a poster is completely covered you only need to check if all the coordinates of this poster are in the dictionary.

See the code below:

```
def is_poster_visible(poster, covered_dict):
  for coord in range(poster[0], poster[0]+poster[1]):
    if not covered_dict.get(coord):
      return True
  return False

def output_visible_posters(poster_input):
  rev_input = poster_input.copy()
  rev_input.reverse()
  covered_dict = {}
  visible_posters = []
  for poster in rev_input:
    if is_poster_visible(poster, covered_dict):
      #if poster is visible, have to put in dict that some parts are now covered
      for coord in range(poster[0], poster[0] + poster[1]):
        covered_dict[coord] = True
      visible_posters.append(poster)
  return visible_posters
```

This gives you the list of posters which are partially visible. To get the number simply return the length of the list.